# Given multiple start dates, how to assign counts to relative date values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to create a before-and-after graph in Excel, lining up multiple milestone dates at month zero, and assigning relative month numbers to months prior and subsequent to milestone month.

My spreadsheet has about 5,000 rows and it looks something like this:

```
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  UserID    |MilestoneDate| 2014-01 | 2014-02 | 2014-03 | 2014-04 | 2014-05 | 2014-06 |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    7       | 2014-01-02  | 232     | 22      | 19      | 77      | 11      | 89      |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    89      | 2014-04-02  | 345     | 45      | 564     | 13      | 122     | 77      |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    678     | 2014-03-11  | 55      | 14      | 17      | 222     | 109     | 111     |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    897     | 2014-03-07  | 234     | 56      | 201     | 19      | 55      | 78      |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    789     | 2014-02-22  | 331     | 33      | 67      | 108     | 111     | 56      |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    989     | 2014-01-09  | 12      | 89      | 97      | 125     | 323     | 99      |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

MilestoneDate = the day that a user downloaded an app, with month columns representing per-month counts for user visits to a website.

Ultimately I'd like to generate a line chart with relative month # on the X-axis and all MilestoneDate months set to zero. Visits prior to MilestoneDate should count on respective negative months (for instance, User 89's March activity should occur on month '-1', and his Feb activity on month '-2').

I'm at a loss for how I might accomplish this in Excel (Programmatically create a new table with offset values - how?). I don't even know what a chart like this is called, which has made Googling for help not very easy.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand this table. How can a user whose start date is in march have a value for 2014-01, which I presume is January. Or what do the labels in row 1 stand for?

Comment: @teylyn - Sorry for the confusion. Date values = when an event (milestone) occurred, in this instance, when website users downloaded a mobile app for a site that they already regularly visit. I edited the table & question to make this a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

See if this fits the bill.

A table needs to be created for the chart source. In this table, the users are listed in the same order as in the original data source. Each user's StartDate is inspected and an Offset is calculated in A16 and below using

```
=MONTH(B5)-MONTH(MonthZero)
```

The labels in row 15 from -5 to 6 are entered manually. A formula populates the table starting in C16, copied down and across

```
=IF(IFERROR(OFFSET($C5:$H5,0,$A16+C$15,1,1),NA())=$A5,NA(),IF(IFERROR(OFFSET($C5:$H5,0,$A16+C$15,1,1),NA())=$B5,NA(),IFERROR(OFFSET($C5:$H5,0,$A16+C$15,1,1),NA())))
```

The formula grabs the user's original data and positions it relative to the join month using the calculated offset. Two nested IFs are used to avoid the user names and their join date appearing in the table, and IFError ensures that only valid offsets are returned.

Then create a line chart with rows 14 and 15 as the X axis and the userID's as the series.

[image]

I've shared the [file used to create the screenshot](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!2723&authkey=!ABPLoCT3M7Lznjk&ithint=file%2cxlsx) on my OneDrive.

**Note:** This kind of data visualisation should not be attempted with 5000 series for 5000 users. You would want to aggregate the data in some way.

Edit: Here's another version with a different formula. I've started another sheet and arranged the original data in columns A to H and the chart source side by side in columns J and following.

The Offset function is volatile and will cause slowness. This index function now in cell L5 and copied across and down is much shorter, faster, and delivers the same result.

```
=IFERROR(IF($J5+L$4>=0,INDEX($C5:$H5,($J5+L$4)+1),NA()),NA())
```

[image]

You can find this on Sheet 2 in the OneDrive file.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here @teylyn, but I'm struggling to apply this to my data set. It's probably out of human error on my part.

Comment: I made an edit with a slightly different approach.